# Spoj task Bonus: ARRAYSUB - subarraysZadanie runtime error (NZEC) {c#}

Tags: c#

Good morning I ran into a problem because look at the Bonus task: ARRAYSUB - subarrays task
it gives me a **runtime error (NZEC)** although ideone is not showing any error https://ideone.com/1eiciI Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
 
namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
 
            int k;
 
            int val = 0;
 
            int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            k = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
 
            for (int i = 0; i < n - k + 1; i++)
            {
                val = arr[i];
                for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++)
                {
                    if (val < arr[j])
                    {
                        val = arr[j];
                    }
                }
 
                Console.Write(val + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to solve task and get accpeted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might help u
this type of error - when the program throws an exception. In this task, probably incorrectly loaded input or exceeding the range.

I propose:

```
 int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: that solve my problem but i have another isssue spoj displaying  time limit exceeded